# Sizing ionic menu during resize

Tags: android, ios, css, ionic-framework

I'm a newbie to Ionic framework. I'm just trying to keep the menu open when the width is greater than the height of the screen by using the following code.

```
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function (viewInfo, state) {
    (window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth) ? $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(true) : $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(false);
  });

  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(window.orientation !== 0);
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    (window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth) ? $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(true) : $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(false);
  });
```

The above code is working as expected. Now the problem is, if you re-size the window when the menu is visible, the menu is only occupying the maximum width of the screen unless the height > width.

Is there any way to check the width of all visible views? So  that I can hide the menu when the width of the main view goes less than the width of menu view.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `expose-aside-when` so the side menu stays open check out the link below

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/exposeAsideWhen/